# Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0') version about python

Tags: python

When I run this commas:

> sudo pip install Notebook

and then this is the error :

```
 The directory '/Users/wangfei/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/wangfei/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting Notebook
  Downloading notebook-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.9MB 162kB/s 
Collecting jinja2 (from Notebook)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 3.8MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Notebook)
Collecting ipykernel (from Notebook)
  Downloading ipykernel-4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 6.4MB/s 
Collecting nbconvert (from Notebook)
  Downloading nbconvert-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (372kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 2.6MB/s 
Collecting jupyter-client (from Notebook)
  Downloading jupyter_client-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 4.6MB/s 
Collecting nbformat (from Notebook)
  Downloading nbformat-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 6.0MB/s 
Collecting tornado>=4 (from Notebook)
  Downloading tornado-4.4.2.tar.gz (460kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 2.1MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-n8SRPH/tornado/setup.py", line 184, in <module>
        **kwargs
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 320, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 386, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2307, in require
        items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 854, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.4.1 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0'))

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-n8SRPH/tornado/
lisicongdeMBP:pro wangfei$
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have `six 1.4.1` installed, but the module requires `1.6` or greater. Running `sudo pip install --upgrade six` should fix your problem.